# How to delete pandas rows where a column value is permutation of another?

Tags: python, pandas, string, permutation

I have values in a column which in the format "number1_number2", but there are permutations of them that are "number2_number1". I need to delete one of the duplicates, does not matter which, but cannot think of how to do so.

I was thinking of parsing them into a left and right side and seeing if they were left1 = right 2 etc.

Here's an example of data

```
    col1    col2        col3            col4    col5        col6    col7
0   143201  -0.339289   aaaaaaaaaaaaa   271521  -2.038760   13.75   143201-271521
1   143201  -0.339289   aaaaaaaaaaaaa   378047  1.471059    13.75   143201-378047
2   271521  -2.038760   aaaaaaaaaaaaa   378047  1.471059    13.25   271521-378047
3   271521  -2.038760   aaaaaaaaaaaaa   143201  -2.038760   -13.75  271521-143201
4   143201  -0.339289   aaaaaaaaaaaaa   37059   0.000000    2.00    143201-37059
```

Rows 0 and 3 are telling me the same information and I need to get rid of one of them, doesn't matter which.

Comment: Could you edit your question to include sample data and any code you've tried so far?

Comment: Maybe `df[~df['col'].str.split('_').apply(sorted).str.join('_').duplicated()]` ..?

Comment: @ChrisAdams That works really well, thanks a lot! If you want to make a post I can mark it as correct.